# Recoverable fatal error on WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a problem with my WordPress [site](http://www.medical-promotion.de/)

I've updated some plugins and after updating, I now receive the following error message when trying to access my site:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class WP_Term could not be
>   converted to string in
>   /homepages/35/d395311677/htdocs/clickandbuilds/MEDICALpromotion671654/wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/class-et-builder-settings.php
>   on line 633

I've checked that line of code and also tried deleting and reuploading that particular Divi file - that didn't help. You can see the the code in question below

```
return is_array( $terms ) ? implode( ',', $terms ) : '';
```

is line 633, that's apparently causing a problem.  Since I'm a total PHP beginner, the code doesn't really tell me anything... :(

I hope you can help!

I've tried:

Updating all plugins.
Deleting an reuploading the original Divi file in question. 
Replaced the code in the file with the code from a brand new Divi file download.

```
protected static function _get_object_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
        return is_array( $terms ) ? implode( ',', $terms ) : '';
    }
```

I expected: To be able to access my site.
The actual output is: An recoverable fatal error message.

Comment: Can you put `var_dump($terms);` on the row before `return` and update your question with the results?

Comment: this seems to be a thing. It might be a incompatibility between yoast/ultimatemember/and WPML. 
https://wpml.org/forums/topic/site-is-throwing-a-501-error-when-wpml-is-activated/page/2/

if i see it right, current solution is to download the previous version of WPML, v.4.1
https://wpml.org/download/wpml-multilingual-cms/?section=changelog

Comment: @Beatroot Thank you!! It was the WPML plugin - they have a 4.2.1. version available on their site, fixing the fatal error problem. So I downloaded and installed that and it did the trick!